# How to get yii select query values as array

Tags: php, yii2, laravel-7

I very new in yii as we use pluck() in laravel to get specific column value in a array how can i do same in yii.I am expecting values in array it return as different objects

```
*********My query **********
$get_coupon_ids=Coupon_categories::find()->select(['coupon_id'])->where(['in', 'category',$category_id])->all();

*****************************

*********OutPut****************

[
        {
            "coupon_id": 13
        },
        {
            "coupon_id": 14
        },
        {
            "coupon_id": 15
        }
]

***************************************

*******Expected value *************

[13,14,15]

*********************************
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the column method, it will return the first column of each result.
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail

```php
$get_coupon_ids = Coupon_categories::find()
  ->select(['coupon_id'])
  ->where(['in', 'category', $category_id])
  ->column();
```

or use `array_map`

```php
$get_coupon_ids = Coupon_categories::find()
  ->select(['coupon_id'])
  ->where(['in', 'category', $category_id])
  ->all();

$ids = array_map(fn($id) => $id['coupon_id'], $get_coupon_ids);
```